# Could .env and .env.example files differ in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dotenv

I have some custom configuration variables that only my company uses for the app. We have a dependency and we have to have those env variables to work that class but other people doesn't need those variables since they are not using the class we are using. So I have 5 more key=>value pair in my production .env which are not in .env.example, is this logical? Are there any other place that I should hold custom key variables other than .env

Comment: Actually, we catch the value from env as like `env('APP_NAME', 'Demo')`. In Laravel you can create your own customization file as well, without env

Comment: I have that file, custom.php, so is this a good workflow?, should i just enter the production values in custom.php and get them with config('custom.value') helper

Comment: Its depends upon you, prefer as you want. https://laravel-news.com/creating-configuration-in-laravel

Comment: Add a custom.php that returns an array of key values in your config folder and reference that using config('custom.key'), then add that to the gitignore if needed to not put it in source